# Remove item from cart with session id 0

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a session id for my shopping cart. This ID gets assigned to it when you place it in the shopping cart. For some reason I can't seem to be able to remove the first item that gets placed in the shopping cart. It works fine with other items that get the id 1,2 etc..

Here's the code:

On the index, the button to add something to the shopping cart is this:

```
 <a href="addtocart.php?id=<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"> <img width=21 src=Images/winkelwagen.png></a>
```

Then the code that adds the item to the session['cart']:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['id']) & !empty($_GET['id'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) & !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){

        $items = $_SESSION['cart'];
        $cartitems = explode(",", $items);
        if(in_array($_GET['id'], $cartitems)){
            header('location: homepagina.php?status=incart');
        }else{
            $items .= "," . $_GET['id'];
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
            header('location: homepagina.php?status=success');

        }

    }else{
        $items = $_GET['id'];
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $items;
        header('location: homepagina.php?status=success');
    }

}else{
    header('location: homepagina.php?status=failed');
}
?>
```

The shopping cart itself:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("header.php");
include_once("dbconnect.php");

if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    echo "U heeft geen producten in uw winkelwagen";

} else { 

$items = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);


?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $total = '';
                        $i=1;

                        foreach ($cartitems as $key=>$id) { 
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
                            $res=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

                            $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM brewery WHERE code = $r[brewery_code]";
                            $resb=mysqli_query($conn, $sqlb);
                            $rb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resb);
                        ?>  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <div class="media">
                            <img class="thumbnail pull-left" src="Images/<?php echo $r['name'] ?>.jpg" width="85" height="152" alt="..."  >
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $r['name']; ?></h4>
                                <h5 class="media-heading"> by <?php echo $rb['name'];; ?></a></h5>
                                <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>In Stock</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                        <input type="amount" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <?php 

                             $total = $total + $r['price'];
                             $i++;  
                            ?>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>€ <?php echo number_format($r['price'],2);?> </strong></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>$14.61</strong></td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <a href="delcart.php?remove=<?php echo $key; ?>">Verwijderen</a>
                        </button></td>
                    </tr>

                        <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td><h5>Subtotal<br>Estimated shipping</h5><h3>Total</h3></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$24.59<br>$6.94</strong></h5><h3>$31.53</h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>   </td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Continue Shopping </button></td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Checkout  
    </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

                        <?php } ?>
```

This is the delete button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <a href="delcart.php?remove=<?php echo $key; ?>">Verwijderen</a> </button></td>
```

And here is the delcart.php code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$items = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);
if(isset($_GET['remove']) & !empty($_GET['remove'])){
    $delitem = $_GET['remove'];
    unset($cartitems[$delitem]);
    $itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;
}
header('location:winkelwagen.php');

?>
```

I can't seem to figure out why it can't delete the first one. I hope you can help me out, thanks.

Here's a gif of the issue: https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/ChiefWeepyGroundbeetle

Comment: I figured it out myself, I change the !empty to NULL. in delcart.php.

Answer (score 0):

**!empty(0) returns false**, so you didn't go into the if. You can remove it, or replace it with **is_numeric($_GET['id'])**. You also need to use **&&** instead of **&**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
...
```